# Terminal stays busy after sh script is started from the python file

Tags: python, terminal, sh, release

I have weird issue. I run a python program with a code like:

```
# file.py
some stuff
some stuff...
os.system(". ./script.sh; function_1")
```

and the content of script.sh:

```
function_1()
{
kill -2 $(pidof python file.py)
python file2.py
}
```

And everything works well etc but after file2 ends its job, terminal stays like it would be still in this program. I have to manually hit Ctrl+C. I tried adding to te script.sh commands like: 
    kill -2 $(pidof python file.py)
or even
    kill all python
but it did't work either.

Of course when I start file2.py manually it performs its jobs and releases terminal right after that.

After this part of the script:

```
kill -2 $(pidof python file.py)
```

terminal is indeed released so it should be possible with a file2.py as well.

Maybe terminal is not released due to the script and not by the python actually. Nevertheless I don’t know how to overcome it. Command:

```
killall bash
```

exits terminal entirely - which is not a good solution.

---

UPDATE: May be important: 
when I just type into terminal . script.sh; function_1 it runs and exits as expected.

I think that the issue is not related to python cause I added

```
printf "test message" -> after python file2.py
```

and it is being shown. But terminal still persists "busy"

Another update:
when I added command to the script so the same file is being started again

```
kill -2 $(pidof python file.py)
python file.py
```

It starts and immediately shows an error "EOF Error"

---

Am I missing something?

Comment: I ran `python file.py` with no problem and it called the script which called `file2.py`. Could we see more of the contents of the two python files? I think the problem may be in there.

Comment: I can write about it but maybe more important info is the fact that when I just type into terminal . script.sh; function_1 it runs and exits as expected

Comment: I made my question more focused so it is more precise now

Comment: To clarify: why are you trying to kill the parent process when `os.system` is the last thing in it anyway?

Comment: Good question - cause file2.py actually deletes the file.py and places another file in its place. So the first file (file.py) has to be stopped to ensure error-free process.

Comment: @szafran: Deleting that file doesn’t actually interfere with Python running it—unlike some shells, it reads the whole thing before starting to execute it.

Comment: Second file also removes and changes content of the whole folder/directory. This is menu-containing program. When I performed this operation without closing that program before and eq go up one level in menu it acts like every other file was missing from the directory (json file etc)..